# SQL - ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY) not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-order-by, analytic-functions

It doesn't matter what I put in the `ORDER BY` clause, the order of the result set doesn't change.

```
WITH Results AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        MessageThreadUsers.threadFK, 
        MessageThreads.threadDate, 
        Messages.MessageBody, 
        Messages.senderFK,
        Users.userFullName AS senderFullName, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MessageThreads.threadDate DESC) AS RowNumber

    FROM MessageThreadUsers
        JOIN MessageThreads ON MessageThreadUsers.threadFK = MessageThreads.threadID
        JOIN Messages ON MessageThreads.threadDate = Messages.messageDate
        JOIN Users ON Messages.senderFK = Users.userID

    WHERE userFK = 'usr_developer'
) 
SELECT * FROM Results WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN 1 AND 10
```

Comment: Which database is this? SQL Server? Which version?

Comment: The ORDER BY in the OVER clause is for the ROW_NUMBER only -- the ORDER BY is the only means of controlling the order of the final result set.

Comment: I thought that this construct is how you page through results. Can you suggest how I would page this query in SQL 2008?

Comment: @JohnSaunders: out of interest, if you call SQL Server "the database", what do you call the database (such as AdventureWorks)?

Comment: @onedaywhen: I was in a hurry. I should have said, "database system" or something like that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ORDER BY only controls the order of returned rows when it is applied to the outermost SELECT statement.

This may work better:

```
WITH Results AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        MessageThreadUsers.threadFK, 
        MessageThreads.threadDate, 
        Messages.MessageBody, 
        Messages.senderFK,
        Users.userFullName AS senderFullName, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MessageThreads.threadDate DESC) AS RowNumber

    FROM MessageThreadUsers
        JOIN MessageThreads ON MessageThreadUsers.threadFK = MessageThreads.threadID
        JOIN Messages ON MessageThreads.threadDate = Messages.messageDate
        JOIN Users ON Messages.senderFK = Users.userID

    WHERE userFK = 'usr_developer'
) 
SELECT * FROM Results WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN 1 AND 10
ORDER BY RowNumber
```

Comment: OK, I guess I don't understand how I'm supposed to use this construct to page result sets. Can you offer a suggestion to page these results?

Comment: I SEE! I didn't notice the new "ORDER BY ThreadDate" at the bottom of your answer.

Comment: I just updated it.  ORDER BY RowNumber is better in this case.